# $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(1-i \xi) y^2} dy$ using complex analytic continuation method

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to compute the integral $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(1-i \xi) y^2} dy$. Instead of doing a crazy complex contour integral, I want to use a complex continuation method.

Let $f(z) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-z y^2} dy$ and $g(z) = \frac 1 2 \sqrt{\frac{\pi} z}$. Both of these functions are defined for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $Re(z) > 0$.

I know that $g$ is holomorphic in the complex half plane, but I don't know how to prove that $f$ is as well.

Since they are holomorphic and agree on positive real values, they agree everywhere in the complex half plane (where the real component is positive). In particular, they agree for $z = 1 - i \xi$. Therefore, $$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(1-i \xi) y^2} dy = \frac 1 2 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1 - i\xi}}.$$

Any help would be appreciated in proving that the function $f$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Do you know the theorem of dominated convergence? If you do, just compute the limit that defines the derivative of f at each point and use that result to show it exists.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how dominated convergence relates to the function being holomorphic. Aren't I supposed to show that $f'(z)$ is defined for all $Re(z) > 0$?

Comment: Yes. I am suggesting you show that the derivative exists by actually showing that the limit that defines it exists.

Comment: $f'(z) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac 1 h (f(z + h) - f(z)) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac 1 h (\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(z+h)y^2} - e^{-z y^2} dy ) $ $=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac 1 h (\int_0^{\infty} e^{-z y^2} ( e^{-h^2 y^2} -1 )dy)  = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac 1 h \cdot 0 = 0$.

So the derivative is 0 everywhere, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Okay, actually, it makes a lot of sense because $f$ is an integral. Thanks!!

Comment: No, the derivative is not zéro everywhere. Notice that you **know** the function is not constant, at least in the positive reals...

Comment: Prove that $\int _0 ^{n} e^{{-zy^{2}}} dy$ is analytic and that this converges uniformly for $\Re z >\epsilon$ to $f(z)$. There are many ways of proving analyticity of f and this is one.